# How can I make the compile task in SBT depend on a java source-processor library (spring-boot-configuration-processor)

Tags: scala, spring-boot, sbt

How do I configure my compile task to depend on the `spring-boot-configuration-processor` library?

The [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor) gives an example using Gradle's `dependsOn` function for the `compileJava` task:

```
    ...
    dependencies {
        optional "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
    }

    compileJava.dependsOn(processResources)
}
```

Can someone show me how a similar task could be created for an SBT build file? Can this even work with Scala source code?

## EDIT:

The `spring-boot-annotation-processor` reads metadata on Classes annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` and generates meta-data to help with IDE code completion and documentation reading. i.e. Saves you from manually typing out well formed JSON docs that describe each of your configuration properties.

To answer @Haspemulator the library generates resources from source code.

Comment: What exactly does this `spring-boot-configuration-processor`? Generates some source code? Or maybe it generates resources? Or downloads some libs into classpath? Anyways, it's all possible in SBT, however you need to describe what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
sourceGenerators in Compile <+= Def.task {
  run processor code
  return list of generated files
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post. Thanks!